# Display an alert when a condition is verify using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form. When no input field is empty, an alert is displayed. When an error occurs(empty field submitted), a class is added to the input to apply a style on it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".form-register").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            if($(this).find('.error')){
                $(".error").animate({'margin-left': '0'});
                $(this).find('input').removeClass('error');
                $(this).find('select').removeClass('error');
            }

            var email = $(this).find('input[name="email"]').val();
            if(!email){
                $(this).find('input[name="email"]').addClass('error');
                alert('Email can not be empty');
            }

            var name = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
            if(!name){
                $(this).find('input[name="name"]').addClass('error');
                alert('Name can not be empty');
            }

            if($(this).find('.error')){
                $(".error").animate({'margin-left': '15px'});
            }else{
                alert('No error has been detected.');
            }

        });
    });

</script>

<style>
    .form-register input.error {
        border:1px solid #F5192F;
        box-shadow:0 0 4px #F5192F;
    }
</style>

<form class="form-register" method="post" action="">
    <input name="email" type="text"/>
    <input name="name" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to display an alert when the fields are not empty but no way. Kindly help me fix this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if($(this).find('.error')) {` will always be true as even if no element with class error is present in the form, jQuery will return an empty array. Change the code to `if($(this).find('.error').length > 0){` to display the alert `alert('No error has been detected.')`.